# Duplicate key name 'unique_id'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is the sql, however, there is an error says "***#1061 - Duplicate key name 'unique_id'*** ", what is the problem.

```
create table `users`(
   uid int(11) auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`unique_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=877888 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove this line

```
UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
```

since `unique_id` is already `Primary Key`. and `Primary Keys` are **unique**.

full `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
create table `users`
(
   uid int(11) auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,   -- specified here
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`unique_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=877888 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db9d4)

Comment: Thanks, I remove the statement, however, #1061 - Duplicate key name 'email'  is occurred,why?

Comment: because `email` already exist. try `UNIQUE KEY email_uq (email)` see here for demo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac712

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean email already exists? and why we can specify UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`)

Comment: because as you can see you have already define that column as unique, see line number 5 of your  `CREATE TABLE` statement. actually you can ignore this one, see this, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf941